# trying to center an image in my nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar.  I have 3 pictures.  I want one to pull right, one to pull left, and one to be in the center.  I got the right and left, can't figure out how to center the last image.  Tried CSS and wrapping it in a `<p>`, but it makes a separate line from the rest of the images.
  Is there some CSS/bootstrap/html trick I'm not aware of?

```
<div class="nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
  <img class="contactPicture pull-center" src="img/gmailIcon.png">
           <img class="contactPicture pull-left" src="img/githubIcon.png">
      <img class="contactPicture pull-right" src="img/linkedinIcon.png">


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the class `text-center` To `.container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay folks, figure this one out.  Put the image, in a row, in a col.  Put the trouble image as a brand.  here's my html

```
<div class="nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="contactPicture pull-left" src="img/githubIcon.png">
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="navbar-brand-gmail" href="#"><img class="contactPicture gmail" src="img/gmailIcon.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="contactPicture pull-right" src="img/linkedinIcon.png">
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

here's my custom css, taken from here http://www.bootply.com/9SOuY3vHlF

```
.navbar-brand-gmail {
   position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0;
margin: auto;}
```

the only thing I changed was adding padding top to zero, so it's in line with the other images.

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that the images are in relative positioning. You should just re-order your html?

So instead of:

```
<img class="contactPicture pull-center" src="img/gmailIcon.png">
<img class="contactPicture pull-left" src="img/githubIcon.png">
<img class="contactPicture pull-right" src="img/linkedinIcon.png">
```

You want:

```
<img class="contactPicture pull-left" src="img/githubIcon.png">
<img class="contactPicture pull-center" src="img/gmailIcon.png">
<img class="contactPicture pull-right" src="img/linkedinIcon.png">
```

if all else fails you can wrap it in a  which may or may not work depending on your css.

Comment: Note: pull-center should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built it way to do this so you'll (most likely) have to position it yourself. Here's an example.

See Snippet.

```css
.footer-img-center {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="nav navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="contactPicture pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/f00">
    <img class="contactPicture footer-img-center" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/fff">
    <img class="contactPicture pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I said there **MAY** not be a built in way as in Bootstrap itself, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no "pull-center" in bootstrap, you can keep your markup the same and add the following to the CSS:

```
.nav .container {text-align:center;}
```

http://www.bootply.com/hsZ9HaJJmO